# Tableau:How to ensure that 5 rows are displayed irrespective of how many data actually have

Tags: tableau-api

[image: tableau]

I am displaying top 5 sales of subcategory of each category. However some categories only have 4 subcategory.

How do I ensure that 5 rows in the table are consistently generated under each category irrespective of how many sub-categories there are.

Comment: What do you want to have happen if there are more than 5 sub-categories in a category?

Comment: Hi Sam, I would like to show an row with any subcategory name and sales value of 0

Comment: If there are only 4 subcategories for the parent category, what do you want the visualization to show. Make up fake data?

Comment: Hi Alex, yes. show a empty row, or with null values. is that achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using outer joins. Your first table will need to be a list of categories. If you don't have a master lookup list of categories, you can use Custom SQL to create one: `select distinct categories from mytable`.

Then you need a subcategories table. If you don't have one, use custom SQL: `select distinct subcategories from mytable`.

Then outer join to the data table, using categories and subcategories as the joins. Since it's an outer join, you will see all possible categories and subcategories and nulls for missing values.

Answer (score 0):

As per my research so far, seems it is only achievable by modifying the data-source itself

Tableau can only show those records which are present. The only instance where it works with missing records is when its a continuous date field.

The above approach is correct. As alternative, you can use the below method:

Step 1:

Using ZN(Lookup) function to fill in empty values with 0

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/populating-empty-cells-with-zeros-existing-data

Step 2:

Exported the worksheet to a new excel file.

Step 3:

Use tableau to connect to the new excel file and perform the below analysis.

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/finding-top-n-within-category